# Change Cursor Theme For Debian 12

Tags: debian, gdm3

I am using:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

My GDM version is:

```
$ gdm3 --version
GDM 43.0
```

I have disabled wayland and using xorg.

Details Of Debian User:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | rg gdm
Debian-gdm:x:112:121:Gnome Display Manager:/var/lib/gdm3:/bin/false
```

The icon is located in `/usr/share/icons/Bibata-Modern-Ice`.

Following [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GDM#Changing_the_cursor_theme), I have run the following commands:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:Debian-gdm
/usr/bin/sudo -u Debian-gdm dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'Bibata-Modern-Ice'
```

It did not change the theme.

Again, I have also tried `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults`.

```
[org/gnome/desktop/interface]
cursor-theme='Bibata-Modern-Ice'
cursor-size=32
text-scaling-factor=1.25
gtk-theme='Solarized-DarkArc-Cyan'
icon-theme='Solarized-Dark-Cyan-Numix'
```

Then ran `sudo dconf update`.

Still The cursor theme is not changing (though it changed the cursor size).

What can I do?

Comment: The issue was `/usr/share/icons/Bibata-Modern-Ice` was a symlink. I changed it into a real folder and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Desktops make everything difficult. Low level Debian alternatives declare your choice of this kind of thing. Hopefully, your desktop will obey. Alternatives are stored/examined via symbolic links in /etc/alternatives. It is a good idea to look at its contents, but alternatives are supposed to be modified via update-alternatives.

```bash
update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```